# Descendent print C array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, reverse

What is wrong with my program, supposed to print the array's content in descendent order?

Output wanted:

```
500
400
300
200
100
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int numar[]={100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
int *pnumar;

pnumar=numar;

for (int contor=5;contor>0;contor--)
{
     pnumar--;
    printf("%d \n", *pnumar ) ;
   
}
}
```

Comment: You assigned the first element of numar to the pointer `pnumar`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to access unallocated memory. When you do
pumar=numar the pointer start pointing to the starting address of array numar and the decrement is causing the loop to access unallocated memory. If you want to access array data in reverse order then simply replace for loop with this

```
for (int contor=4;contor>=0;contor--){
printf("%d \n", pnumar[contor] ) ;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment, your pointer points the **first** element of your array ("100"), not the last one.

At the very first operation, you decrement your pointer making it go backward, which makes it point outside your array even before your program has one chance to print out a number.

Pointer arithmetic states that you can use:

```
pnumar=numar+4;
```

… to shift it to the required position. Later, you probably want to use indexing operator `[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: sort the array to put it into the order you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int order_descending(const void *p1, const void *p2)
  {
  return *(int *)p2 - *(int *)p1;
  }

int main()
  {
  int numar[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
  int *pnumar;
  int nArray_count = (sizeof(numar) / sizeof(numar[0]));

  pnumar = numar;

  qsort(numar, nArray_count, sizeof(numar[0]), order_descending);

  for (int i = 0 ; i < nArray_count ; i++)
    printf("%d \n", *pnumar++);
  }
```

[Run it at OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ4C1XiAv)

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `pnumar` to `numar`, it stores the address of the first integer in the array. So in the first iteration of the for loop, when it decrements it exits the array. Instead of `pnumar = numar`, do `pnumar = numar + 5`, which will go to the address after the last element in `numar`. It should run properly then.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has the assignment `pnumar = numar;` which makes `pnumar` point to the start of the array.

Since you want to loop through in reverse, you will want something like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int numar[] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };
    int *pnumar;
    pnumar = &numar[4];
    for (int contor = 5; contor > 0; contor--) {
       printf("%d\n", *pnumar);
       pnumar--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The assignment `pnumar = &numar[4];` makes `pnumar` point to the *last* element of the array.

Then, in your loop, you can decrement the pointer (`pnumar--;`) *after* printing, not before.

(Side note: your code was missing a `return` statement at the end).

Answer (score 0):

As Sergeant Cortez explained, you'd like the pointer to start at the end, not at the beginning, of the array, so you fix this, for example, by adding this statement just above the for loop:

```
pnumar += 5;
```

There are other constructs merging the two 'pnumar =' statements, and not using a hard-coded 5, but this should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

After this assignment

```
pnumar=numar;
```

the pointer `pnumar` points to the first element of the array `numar`.

Within the loop the pointer is decremented

```
pnumar--;
```

So even in the first iteration of the loop the pointer points to beyond the array and the program has undefined behavior.

You should not use magic numbers like `5` in programs.

If you want to output elements of the array using a pointer then the variable `contor` is redundant.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int numar[] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };

    for ( const int *pnumar = numar + sizeof( numar ) / sizeof( *numar ); pnumar != numar; )
    { 
        printf( "%d\n", *--pnumar );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
500
400
300
200
100
```

You could write a separate function that outputs an array in the reverse order in any stream. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * reversed_output( const int a[], size_t n, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( const int *p = a + n; p != a; )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d\n", *--p );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main( void )
{
    int numar[] = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 };


    fputc( '\n', reversed_output( numar, sizeof( numar ) / sizeof( *numar ), stdout ) );
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above with one additional empty line.

```
500
400
300
200
100
```